# Do Half-elves count as Humans for the Favored Enemy class feature?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, races, ranger

I have Favored Enemy (Humans). Do half-elves count as humans too?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes they do:

> Elf Blood: Half-elves count as both elves and humans for any effect related to race.

-PRD [Half-Elf Racial Traits](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedRaceGuide/coreRaces/halfElves.html#half-elf-racial-traits)

Comment: Note though that Favored Enemy does not stack with itself - so if you have both Favored Enemy (Humans) and Favored Enemy (Elves) you just get whichever one is higher against half-elves, not the sum of both.

Comment: Should you have a +4 against Humans, and a +2 against Elf's, you would get a +4 against Half-elves.